# How do I refer my friend?

Tags: league-of-legends

Through some quick research online, it seems that the only way to enter your friend's name is when you create your account, but there is no option for this:
[image]

So how do you refer a friend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer people to League of Legends by using the following referral links based on region:

- [Brazil](http://rewards.br.leagueoflegends.com/)
- [EU Nordic & East](http://rewards.eune.leagueoflegends.com/)
- [EU West](http://rewards.euw.leagueoflegends.com/)
- [North America](http://rewards.na.leagueoflegends.com/)
- [Oceanic](http://rewards.oce.leagueoflegends.com/)
- [Turkey](http://rewards.tr.leagueoflegends.com/)

Scroll to the bottom of the page, and you will see the following:
[image]

You will need to agree to the terms before proceeding to the next page. If you are not signed in, the next page will prompt you to login.

On the following page, you will see this:
[image]

From here, you can copy the URL and send it to your friend. Alternatively, you can enter in an email address, where an email with your referral URL will be sent to your friend's email address. After following the URL, your friend will be able to sign up for an account which will count towards your referral bonus.

Comment: So there is no way to simply enter their name? There used to be when you first logged in to the client.

Comment: Not anymore, and I do not know about the old system. All I know is that this is how it's done now. Feel free to ask Riot why they made the change.

Comment: Hahahahahahahahahahaha that was funny. I'm assuming it was a joke and if not then never mind. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @keocey, just know that at least it's not Bungie. If so, we'd probably see pages of people bitching about the lack of a referral system, followed by Bungie giving us one that doesn't work for 6 months. I'll be here all night.